# Generic mapping function where type T & Q have the same keys but different property types

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I am looking to create a reusable RxJS operator that can map from object T to Q. This will be used to convert dates formats. T & Q are therefore different types but only in regard to the properties, the keys remain the same for both.

I think for the most part I am there but running into some typing issues that I can't resolve.

```
export function convertDateTimeToluxon<T extends object, Q extends Record<keyof T, any>>(): (source: Observable<T>) => Observable<Q> {
    return (source: Observable<T>): Observable<Q> => source.pipe(
        map((object: T): Q => {
            const convertedObj: Q = {} as Q;
            Object.keys(object).forEach((key: string) => {
                const typedKeyT: keyof T = key as keyof T;
                if(Datetime.isDateTime(object[typedKeyT])) {
                    convertedObj[typedKeyT] = DateTime.fromISO(object[typedKeyT]);
                } else {
                    convertedObj[typedKeyT] = object[typedKeyT];
                }
            })
            return convertedObj;
        })
    )
}
}
```

The issue occurs on the 2 assignment lines

`convertedObj[typedKeyT] = DateTime.fromISO(object[typedKeyT]);`
`convertedObj[typedKeyT] = object[typedKeyT];`

Where TypeScript is complaining that `T[key of T] is not assignable to Q[key of T]` - I assume this is to do with the any type in the record at the top?

---

**Answer** - this is what i have come up with for the time being, sure it could be improved!

Part of this is taken from geoffreys answer below

```
export function convertDateTimeToLuxon<T extends Record<keyof T, any>, Q extends Record<keyof T, any>>(): (source: Observable<T>) => Observable<Q> {
    return (source: Observable<T>): Observable<Q> => source.pipe(
        map((object: T): Q => {
            const convertedObj: Q = {} as Q;
            Object.keys(object).forEach((key) => {
                const typedKeyT: keyof T = key as keyof T;
                if (DateTime.isDateTime(object[typedKeyT])) {
                    convertedObj[typedKeyT] = DateTime.fromISO(object[typedKeyT]) as Q[keyof T];
                } else {
                    convertedObj[typedKeyT] = object[typedKeyT];
                }
            })
            return convertedObj;
        })
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T extends Record<PropertyKey, any>` solves it. (I also removed unnecessary annotations in a few places):

```js
function convertDateTimeToluxon <T extends Record<PropertyKey, any>, Q extends Record<keyof T, any>>() {
    return (source: Observable<T>): Observable<Q> => source.pipe(
        map((object: T) => {
            const convertedObj = {} as Q;
            Object.keys(object).forEach((key: string) => {
                const typedKeyT = key as keyof T;
                if(Datetime.isDateTime(object[typedKeyT])) {
                    convertedObj[typedKeyT] = DateTime.fromISO(object[typedKeyT]);
                } else {
                    convertedObj[typedKeyT] = object[typedKeyT];
                }
            })
            return convertedObj;
        })
    );
}
```

I'm not sure why this works though. I noticed that `object` was generally requiring more annotations.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, that has solved the issue with the second assignment, but the first one is still having issues due to the following.

`Type 'DateTime' is not assignable to type 'Q[keyof T]'.`

`DateTime is assignable to the constraint of type Q[keyof T], but Q[key of T] could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint any`

I also realised with the help of your answer that i could use `T extends Record<keyof T, any>`

Comment: Solved the 2nd part of the issue, thanks for the help - put me in the right direction

Comment: Yes it's funny that something like `T extends Record<keyof T, any>` works but I think it looks too clever for what it does. If a generic is not needed I think it should not be used as it can confuse maintainers. TS is complex enough as it is.

Comment: Where do you import DateTime from?

Comment: Its from Luxon, we have api data that sends dates in one format and i want a tidy way to convert any of these dates into a Luxon Datetime so that everything inside the application has a standardised way of dealing with / displaying dates. We are explicitly transforming these on a service by service basis at the moment. And this is an attempt to explore making our lives a little easier and having one pipeable operator we can use wherever we need to do this.

Comment: There is something off. You should not be able to pass `object[typedKeyT]` to `fromISO` because it's a `DateTime`

Comment: I would refactor your code like [so](https://tsplay.dev/wX1BVN) to be able to infer the output stream from the input stream by passing in the union of keys which you expect to be associated with a date. Seems more convenient than specifying the input and output type by hand. The function body is also simpler. However you have a legitimate type error in there